# How to stop ProGuard from stripping the Serializable interface from a class

Tags: java, android, proguard, serializable

Is there an explicit way to stop ProGuard from changing a class from implementing an interface?

I have a class that implements `java.io.Serializable`, let's call it `com.my.package.name.Foo`. I've found that after running through ProGuard, it no longer implements `Serializable`. I get `null` after I cast from `Serializable` to `Foo` and `false` if I check an instance with `instanceof Serializable`. I've made sure to set ProGuard to ignore this class:

```
-keep class com.my.package.name.Foo
```

I've also tried:

```
-keep class com.my.package.name.Foo { *; }
```

and I've also tried the whole package by doing this:

```
-keep class com.my.package.name.** { *; }
```

or:

```
-keep class com.my.package.** { *; }
```

and also just to keep all `Serializable` classes:

```
-keep class * implements java.io.Serializable { *; }
```

but to no avail. I have another class in a sibling package (roughly: `com.my.package.name2.Bar`) that also implements `Serializable` and is used similarly but has no issues.

I'm not sure it's relevant, but I'm packing this in a jar for use with Android. The code that uses these classes include putting them in `Bundle`s which is why I need `Serializable`. I considered that perhaps somehow ProGuard thinks that `Foo` is never used as a `Serializable` but that seems unlikely given that I pass it as a parameter to `Bundle.putSerializable(String, Serializable)` and also I do an implicit cast: `Serializable serializable = foo;`. In fact, when I debug, I can see the `Foo` get put into the `Bundle` and I can examine the `Bundle` and see the instance of `Foo` there, but when retrieving it the cast fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ProGuard doesn't ever strip interfaces that are defined in libraries (like Serializable) from classes in code that is processed (like Foo). Library code may be casting to those interfaces, so they can't be removed.

> I get null after I cast from Serializable to Foo

This means that the instance must be null to start with. Your analysis would be correct if you'd get  a ClassCastException. You can check that Foo still implements Serializable with `javap`. The problem probably lies elsewhere. For tips on serialization, you can look at the ProGuard manual > Examples > [Processing serializable classes](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#serializable).

**Update:**

In this case, it turns out to be a configuration problem. ProGuard can only process class files if it knows everything about their hierarchy (just like a compiler). You really have to specify the runtime classes:

```
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
```

or for Android:

```
-libraryjars /usr/local/android-sdk/platforms/android-17/android.jar
```

The Android Ant/Eclipse builds automatically specify all necessary -injars/-outjars/-libraryjars options for you, but in a custom build process, you have to specify them yourself. Cfr. ProGuard manual > Examples > [A complete Android application](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#androidapplication).

Note that the option -dontwarn makes the warnings go away, but not the problems. Only use it if really necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I've checked with `javap` and `Foo` doesn't implement `Serializable` anymore. Your comment about `ClassCastException` makes sense to me too, but it just doesn't seem to work that way. My suspicion is that something has happened in the shrinking and optimization to change the behavior from what you might expect normal Java code to do as at that point it's no longer Java, but byte-code.

Comment: I've found that if I have ProGuard set to `-dontshrink` and then explicitly use `-keep,allowoptimization,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation Foo` then `Foo` will still implement `Serializable`, but unfortunately that's not a solution for me as I'd like shrink to be on in general.

Comment: If you have a small sample that illustrates the problem, I'll look into it. You can find my mail address on the Feedback page of the ProGuard website.

Answer (score 47):

I had the same issue fixed using below config.

```
-keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    !static !transient <fields>;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```

Official Documentation
http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#serializable

Comment: In my opinion, this should have been a default rule in proguard.

Comment: Thank you! I've spent so much time trying to get this to work.