# serialized lambda and no serialVersionUID?

Tags: java, serialization, lambda, java-8, serialversionuid

I'm trying to learn how the serialization works with Java and its lastest version. I'm trying to serialize a lambda like this :

```
Runnable r = (Runnable & Serializable)() -> {System.out.println("This is a test");};
```

But I notice that I have no warning about the absence of a `serialVersionUID` variable. Is it normal ?

I know it will be generated at the runtime however it is strongly recommended to define it : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

> If a serializable class does not explicitly declare a serialVersionUID, then the serialization runtime will calculate a
>   default serialVersionUID value for that class based on various aspects
>   of the class, as described in the Java(TM) Object Serialization
>   Specification. However, it is strongly recommended that all
>   serializable classes explicitly declare serialVersionUID values, since
>   the default serialVersionUID computation is highly sensitive to class
>   details that may vary depending on compiler implementations, and can
>   thus result in unexpected InvalidClassExceptions during
>   deserialization. Therefore, to guarantee a consistent serialVersionUID
>   value across different java compiler implementations, a serializable
>   class must declare an explicit serialVersionUID value. It is also
>   strongly advised that explicit serialVersionUID declarations use the
>   private modifier where possible, since such declarations apply only to
>   the immediately declaring class--serialVersionUID fields are not
>   useful as inherited members. Array classes cannot declare an explicit
>   serialVersionUID, so they always have the default computed value, but
>   the requirement for matching serialVersionUID values is waived for
>   array classes.

What should I do ? How can I define it in my Lambda ?

Thanks

Comment: There seems to be no way to declare a field `serialVersionUID` due to the lack of a defining class. And that directly leads to the next question: For what reason should a lambda be serializable? It has not fields and thus no data!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose A serialized lambda contains values that were captured at the time the lambda was evaluated. If a lambda is evaluated several times with different captured values, the objects embodying the lambdas will differ, and so will their serialized representations.

Comment: @StuartMarks Obviously I didn't think far enough. Thanks for pointing this out. In fact, it helped me changing (building?) my mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `serialVersionUID` is only relevant to classes which generate a [stream identifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectStreamClass.html). This is not the case if the serializable class has a `writeReplace()` method (also described in the [`Serializable` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)) that returns a substitute object of a different class, as such a representation is fully decoupled from the original class. This is what happens with serializable lambda instances, see [`SerializedLambda`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/SerializedLambda.html):

> Implementors of serializable lambdas, such as compilers or language runtime libraries, are expected to ensure that instances deserialize properly. One means to do so is to ensure that the `writeReplace` method returns an instance of `SerializedLambda`, rather than allowing default serialization to proceed.

So it’s an instance of `SerializedLambda` that ends up on the stream and thus the responsibility of that class to have a stable serialized representation. Unfortunately that doesn’t protect you from possible incompatibilities.

Upon deserialization, a synthetic method of the class defining the lambda expression will get called (compare to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28960234/2711488) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084460/2711488)) which will reject deserialization attempts which do not match an existing definition of a lambda expression within that class, whereas the matching may depend on subtle aspects of the lambda’s definition. Note that even recompiling the defining class with Eclipse rather than `javac` might break the Serialization compatibility.

Not also the [security impacts of `Serializable` lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25443655/2711488). Generally, I recommend to avoid using it.